# how to post on linkedin group in php

Tags: php, linkedin-api

```
$ln->fetch("POST","/v1/groups/1483367/posts", "")
```

I am new to linkedin Api i am not understanding how the things are working in linkedin api.

Linkedin share code is below i come to know how this is working as below but i need to know how to work with group post(i am already a member of that group and i am login to linkedin while posting my post to group)

```
$ln->fetch('POST','/v1/people/~/shares',
    array(
        'comment' => 'Hello Linkedin',
        'content' => array(
            'title' => 'SimpleLinkedIn (SLinkedin)',
            'description' => 'Open source OAuth2 Implementation for PHP and linkedin.',
            'submittedUrl' => 'https://github.com/EJTH/SLinkedIn/'
        ),
        'visibility' => array('code' => 'anyone' )
    )
));
```

Comment: There is no buddy to help me out :( please help me...

Answer (score -1):

This page describes how to POST to a LinkedIn group that the authenticated user is a member of:  https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#create

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kamyar i have already been there but i do't understand how i can implement in my php code as i have done for sharing.